# Check if data exist in a node that was referenced from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a node for news

`News
         - key
             -title
             -content`

I created a new node called read_news

`ReadNews
         -key
             -news-key: true
             -news-key2: true
             -news-key3: true`

The issue now is that, when i delete all or some entries in the `News` Node from the console, the `ReadNews` node still keeps the reference id for the news deleted. When i run the app it shows two cells instead of an empty RecyclerView.

I did a debugging and i realize the the FirebaseRecylerAdapter still counts the number of items in that node, even though where i am referencing the item in the node from has been deleted.

How can i create a condition to know if the `news-key` does not exist in the `News` node, and FirebaseRecyclerAdapter skips its.

```
mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("newspapers");
        mDatabaseRef.child(getRef(position).getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
                    Log.d("dsmfdvmms", "");
                }else{
                    NewsPaper newsPaper = dataSnapshot.getValue(NewsPaper.class);
                    viewHolder.libraryName.setText(newsPaper.getPaper_name());

                    loadImage(viewHolder.libraryImage, newsPaper.getLogo(), context);

                    vendotName = newsPaper.getPaper_name();
                    vendorIcon = newsPaper.getLogo();
                    vendorId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to verify if a key exists in the second `node` in order to delete it from the other node. When you delete a news in the `News` node, delete the coresponding reference from the `ReadNews` node like this:

```
yourRef.child("ReadNews").child(key).child("news-key").removeValue();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The issue is that, i am not deleting from the app, i deleted them from the console firebase.com and its crashing the app cause it did not exist

Comment: As far as i know you cannot do this manually from the console using `rules`. According to [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) there are rules for `reading`, `writing`, `validate` and `indexOn` and not for deleting items. You can delete items programmatically as mentioned above.

Comment: Yes i have, your answer gave me an idea, but did not the solution to the problem...what i did is, before i add to the adapter item i check if the key is available in the main reference node, if its available i add to the adapter, and if its not i delete the value, cos its reference do not exist.

Comment: I understand. So, best of luck!